# How to find the number of times an item appears in a list of list of strings without using counter, or dictionary in python?

Tags: python

If I have

```
animal = [['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']]
```

and

```
item_to_find = ['cat', 'dog']
```

how do I calculate the number of times each string inside `item_to_find` can be found in `animal`? for example, for `'cat'`, the answer would be 6, and for `'dog'` it would be 3. I need to do this without using `collectiouns.Counter` or a dictionary. I tried to use `count`, but it only works if it's a list of strings, and not a list of list of strings.

I tried to do it this way:

```
for i in item_to_find:
    print(animal.count(i))
```

but like I was saying this only works for a list of strings and not a list of list of strings.

My result would look like something like this: `[6, 3]` (as a list).

Comment: What do you mean "without a counter or dictionary"? Do you mean you're not allowed to use `dict` or anything imported from standard libraries like `collections.Counter`? Can you share what code you've written so far, and explain in more detail where you're stuck?

Comment: yes thats what i mean! and yes I will edit that just a minute please.

Comment: You'd also want to explain in what form the results would need to be collected or written to the screen, since a dictionary would actually make a lot of sense as a data structure here, but apparently you're barred from using it.

Comment: Depending on your use case, and what else you may or may not be doing to the data, you may want to simply [flatten the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists). Whether or not it's a duplicate (this question was closed and reopened), it's probably handy to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum` along with `count` to sum up the counts in all the sub-lists:

```
>>> animal = [['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']]
>>> item_to_find = ['cat', 'dog']
>>> [(item, sum(a.count(item) for a in animal)) for item in item_to_find]
[('cat', 6), ('dog', 3)]
```

If you wanted to avoid using `count` you can do it almost as easily by using a nested generator with `sum`:

```
>>> [(item, sum(i == item for a in animal for i in a)) for item in item_to_find]
[('cat', 6), ('dog', 3)]
```

If you don't want to know which item each count goes with, make it a list of just the counts instead of a tuple that includes the item:

```
>>> [sum(a.count(item) for a in animal) for item in item_to_find]
[6, 3]
```

Comment: and how would I do it if I would want the answer to be [6,3]?

Comment: Remove `(item, ` and `)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iteration:

```py
occurrences = [0] * len(item_to_find)
for sublist in animal:
    for idx, item in enumerate(item_to_find):
        occurrences[idx] += sublist.count(item)
```

Now occurrences will be [6, 3] for the example given.